# How to repeat months in loop ?

Tags: php, mysql, loops

I want to insert dynamic months into database like if user select March then I need to  insert record for 12 months from March to Feburary. I am getting dynamic months but when I am trying to insert it into database it insert only first 12 months. I need to repeat the loop again from March to February if user click on add more button. This is my code :

```
$months = array();
$date="august";
$year= '2014';
//$y= (int)$year;
$currentMonth= date('m', strtotime($date));
$currentyear= date('Y', strtotime('+1 year'));
for($x = $currentMonth; $x < $currentMonth+12; $x++) 
{ 
    $months[] = date('F Y', mktime(0, 0, $currentyear, $x,1));
}
//print_r($months);
for($i=0; $i<=23 ; $i++)
{

 echo $insert= "insert into month(month_name) values('".$months[$i]."')";

}
```

Comment: Actually, it sounds as if your database model is quite strange. Why would you want too insert all twelve months, in some order? 

Moreover, the length of the months array will not exceed 12, so a loop with until 23 will result in an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as your months array only has 12 values, you can't go to value 23 in that array. What you can do is run through the array twice from 0 to 11, like this:

```
for($j=0; $j<2 ; $j++)
{
  for($i=0; $i<12 ; $i++)
  {
    echo $insert= "insert into month(month_name) values('".$months[$i]."')";
  }
}
```

or as clyde indicated you can use a modulo operator, which doesn't make you waste 2 loops and thus is faster:

```
  for($i=0; $i<24 ; $i++)
  {
    echo $insert= "insert into month(month_name) values('".$months[$i % 12]."')";
  }
```

Comment: your wasting two loops on something that could be one, with the use of the modulo operator

Comment: how i can find the dynamic value for 2 in $j loop.

Comment: as your demo doesn't indicate a dynamic value i can't seem to know where your dynamic value should come from. In your demo you also just hard code "23" in there. How should this variable be defined then? is this the "add button" you're talking about?

Comment: i am getting this error when i am trying to add another field with months.Like   for($i=0; $i< 24 ; $i++)
 {
    echo $insert= "insert into month(month_name, sale) values('".$months[$i % 12]."', '".$sale[$i]."')".'<br/>';
 }

Comment: can you please edit the question with this extra question and some explanation about the error? because i can't really see anything from here.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the DateTime object to do this.

```
$string = '01-08-2013'; //input string from user

$StartDate = new DateTime($string); 
$StopDate = new DateTime($string);
$StopDate->modify('+1 year');

while($StartDate < $StopDate) { //loop as long as $StartDate is smaller than $StopDate
    echo "inserting " . $StartDate->format('d/m/Y') . ' into database ' . "<br/>";

    //execute mysql query;

    $StartDate->modify('+1 month');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question should state why you want this series of months in the database, as nobody normally does so. Normally people put timestamps on transactions/event records into a database and then report on them.